# brightcove video display value from Angular Scope

Tags: angularjs

We have a app designed using AngularJS and we have a brightcove video. 
We want to display the parameters values from scope variables.
But when i am trying to assign values from scope I am not able to view the video

```
<object id="" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="playerID" value="**{{app.videoId}}**" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="{{app.Key}}" />
  ........
  ........
  ........
  ........ 
  ........
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
```

I thought the values will be loaded from scope var. But it is not happening.

Comment: The problem is likely that `brightcove.createExperiences()` happens before Angular has replaced "{{app.videoId}}" with the variable value. Have you tried delaying the execution of `brightcove.createExperiences()` or calling it from within your Angular code?

Comment: I havent tried it, how can i call it from Angular code or delay it. can you point me to some code example

Answer (score 0):

So I've have this issue too and finally got a solution for it. The problem I had was that the object was being added to the page before the angular values would be populated, thus having the string of the variables instead of the values.

In the HTML, I put in a div.

And in my controller:

```
<object id="xxxxxx" class="BrightcoveExperience">\
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">\          
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value=' + $scope.videoId + '>\    
    <param name="secureConnections" value="true" />\
    <param name="secureHTMLConnections" value="true" >\
    <param name="forceHTML" value="true" >\
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>');
```

Since my $scope.videoId had a value, when it was added to the page, it worked. I hope that helps out.